# Flutter set state not updating variable value in bottomsheet function

Tags: flutter, setstate, bottom-sheet

I have a button where on click I call the following function which creates a bottomsheet below.What happens is that it builds a list of cards based on a list array value. Then one of the cards I want to update its value based on the onTap gesture. I notice it detects the gesture but does not update its value. Above all I have a global variable defined as

```
String _localPNumberSelected="";
```

In the onTap I call setState

```
setState(() {                                                   
 _localPNumberSelected=vList[index]["pNumber"].toString();
});
```

but this does not update

```
children: [
  new Text('$_localPNumberSelected'),                                                
],
```

Here is the full codes.

```
void _callQuickListModalBottomSheet(context){
    Future<void> future = showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc){
          return Container(
            height: 280,
            margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
            child : new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                 color: Color.fromRGBO(36, 46, 66, 1),
                 borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                   topLeft: const Radius.circular(20),
                   topRight: const Radius.circular(20)
                 ),                 
              ),
              child: new Column(                    
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                        margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                        height:45,
                        child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Card(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Row (
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                              new Column(
                                                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                   Container(
                                                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.green,
                                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(5),
                                                        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(5)
                                                      ),
                                                      ),
                                                  child: Icon(Icons.check, size: 20.0),
                                                  height: 27,
                                                  width: 30,
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                              ),
                                              new Column(
                                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                children: [
                                                        new Text('$_localPNumberSelected'),

                                               ],
                                             ), 
                                      ],
                                    )
                          )
                        ]
                        )
                        ),
                        new Container(
                        height:190,                        
                        child:
                        new ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: vehicleListdata.length,                          
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                            return Container(
                              margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                              width: 30.0,
                              height: 35.0,                         
                                  child: Card(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Row (
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                              new Column(
                                                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                 Container(
                                                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.amber,
                                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(5),
                                                        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(5)
                                                      ),

                                                    ),
                                                  height: 27,
                                                  width: 10,

                                                  ),
                                              ],
                                              ),
                                              new Column(
                                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                children: [
                                                     new GestureDetector(
                                                          onTap: () {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              _localPNumberSelected=vList[index]["pNumber"].toString();
                                                            });
                                                          doSomething(vList[index]["pNumber"].toString());
                                                        }, 
                                                        child:new Text(vList[index]["pNumber"].toString()),    
                                                       ),

                                            ],
                                          ), 
                                      ],
                                    ),


                                  )
                            );

                          }
                        )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
            )
          );
      }
    );
    future.then((void value) => _closeModal(value));
}
```

Comment: Any setState in bottom sheet with not reflect because, It is in a new context. Try making the bottom sheet a stateful widget and self sustain its state in itself. If you wanted to pass the value with `Navigator.of(context).pop('value')`.

Comment: @HemanthRaj is there any example for me to make the stateful widget and can then it communicate with my onTap function

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**See Example** suggested by [yy1300326388](https://github.com/yy1300326388) in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2115#issuecomment-430232979):

```
 String update = 'Oya Update Jhoor';

  void locationSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context,state){
            return Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    updated(state);
                  },
                  child: new Text('$update')),
            );
          });
        });
  }

  Future<Null> updated(StateSetter updateState) async {
    updateState(() {
      update = 'Update Leekan si';
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could simply return a stateful builder that in turn returns the widget you are trying to call.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
context: context,
builder: (context) {
  return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState /*You can rename this!*/) {
    return Container(
      height: heightOfModalBottomSheet,
      child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          heightOfModalBottomSheet += 10;
        });
      }),
    );
  });
```

});

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+change+state+of+Bottomsheet+in+flutter

Link to Original Answer - ShahbazAli (Nov 05 2020).

Answer (score 4):

`showModalBottomSheet` doesn't rebuild itself when you use `setState`. If you want to change values inside a bottomSheet after you have built it, you are going to need to implement your own version of bottomSheet (just create a stateful widget that behaves the same way)

Comment: @seri any example how to move to my own bottomsheet cause if you notice I also need to call a function too in the on tap function.

Comment: @newbie, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2115 take a look at some of the comments in this issue.

Comment: why showModalBottomSheet doesn't rebuild itself when we use setState?

Answer (score 1):

I find it more easy to use ValueNotifier along with ValueListenableBuilder to trigger refresh, this is very helpful when you want to make the changes visible to both your bottom sheet and the main page.

Any update to the `listenToThisValue` variable `(ex listenToThisValue.value = 'abc')` will trigger a refresh anywhere.

```
 late ValueNotifier<String> listenToThisValue = ValueNotifier('xyz');
  
  void test() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: listenToThisValue,
              builder: (context, indicatorEnabled, child) {
                return Text(listenToThisValue.value);
              });
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState /*You can rename this!*/) {
        return Container(
          height: heightOfModalBottomSheet,
          child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              heightOfModalBottomSheet += 10;
            });
          }),
        );
      });
    )
  }
);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for it